# How to create a runnable jar file with AspectJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, aspectj

I'm using Eclipse to compile java code with aspectj.
My code (with the aspect) works fine, but I'm struglling to create a jar file of this my code.

For example, if I select Export > Runnable JAR file, in the combo box I don't see my project (all the other project that not based on aspecj are showing up in the combo box).

Answer (score 2):

If you like to have repeatable builds which work from command line as well as from IDEs like Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA, I recommend a Maven build. The ***onejar-maven-plugin*** creates a runnable JAR including AspectJ runtime and all other declared dependencies for you:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.scrum_master.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.source-target.version>1.7</java.source-target.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.8</aspectj.version>
        <main-class>de.scrum_master.app.Application</main-class>
    </properties>

    <build>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.source-target.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.source-target.version}</target>
                        <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--<showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>-->
                        <source>${java.source-target.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.source-target.version}</target>
                        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                        <complianceLevel>${java.source-target.version}</complianceLevel>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                        <!--<verbose>true</verbose>-->
                        <!--<warn>constructorName,packageDefaultMethod,deprecation,maskedCatchBlocks,unusedLocals,unusedArguments,unusedImport</warn>-->
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                            <phase>process-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>${main-class}</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
                    <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>one-jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <onejarVersion>0.96</onejarVersion>
                        <mainClass>${main-class}</mainClass>
                        <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
                <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>OneJAR googlecode.com</id>
            <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <organization>
        <name>Scrum-Master.de - Agile Project Management</name>
        <url>http://scrum-master.de</url>
    </organization>
</project>
```

Comment: hello @kriegaex - i am getting this message on the same process - No sources found skipping aspectJ compile -  , My code does not have  <mainClass>${main-class}</mainClass> as such , what can be done in such case

Comment: [INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:compile (default) @ Switchlite ---
[INFO] No modifications found skipping aspectJ compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:test-compile (default) @ Switchlite ---
[WARNING] No sources found skipping aspectJ compile
[INFO]

Comment: You do not need to use Exec Maven plugin, it is optional and not the source of your problem. But why do you try to build an executable JAR if there is no main class to execute? If AspectJ Maven plugin does not find any aspect sources, maybe you just have not named your aspects `*.aj` but `*.java` or maybe you put them into the wrong directory. I hope you do have a standard Maven directory layout with e.g. `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`. Maybe it is better to create a question of its own for your problem, not hijack this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a normal run configuration with the same start class as your AspectJ run configuration. When you create your runnable JAR, select the normal run configuration. The resulting JAR will have AspectJ support.

You can find here the answer : 
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/204968/

Answer (score 0):

The [runnable jar exporter only works with `Java Application` type launch configs](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-runnable-jar.htm), but that shouldn't be a problem. Create a normal `Java Application` launch config with your main class and export the runnable jar based on that newly created launch config. It should work.